# MySQL incorrect datetime value error for valid dates

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp column and I get an errors when I try to enter some specific dates and times.

For example `2013-03-31 02:13:11` and `2014-03-31 02:55:00` work, but `2013-03-31 02:55:00` says:

```
SQL Error (1292): Incorrect datetime value
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any special characters around it.

Comment: yes - between date and time is a special char

Comment: So I was Googling and found out that daylight saving time 2013 in Romania began at 3:00 am on Sunday, 31 March. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I don't have any special chars. I just edit it in HeidiSQL manually.

Comment: @SalmanA That makes sense. I think it may be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a daylight saving time issue, especially when you mention that the date causing problem is `2013-03-31 02:55:00`... the date on which most European countries started observing DST for the year 2013. Central Europe Time was advanced by one hour at 2AM which means there was no `02:55:00` on that day!

Note that MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values from the current time zone to UTC for storage and this is where the error is thrown:

```
SET time_zone = 'CET';
-- Central Europe Time in 2013: DST starts at 2am when clocks move forward to 3am
-- see https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/europe-starts-dst-2013.html

INSERT INTO test(timestamp_col) VALUES('2013-03-31 01:59:59');
-- Affected rows: 1  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.078 sec.

INSERT INTO test(timestamp_col) VALUES('2013-03-31 02:00:00');
-- SQL Error (1292): Incorrect datetime value: '2013-03-31 02:00:00' for column 'timestamp_col' at row 1

INSERT INTO test(timestamp_col) VALUES('2013-03-31 03:00:00');
-- Affected rows: 1  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.063 sec.
```

Comment: This kinda makes sense. But it's weird that 2:13 works, while 2:55 doesn't.