# MySQL incorrect datetime value for a specific time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem in MySQL:

this works:

```
INSERT INTO LUFT_DE_VALUES(DATE_TIME,ID_COMP,ID_SCOPE,LUFT_VALUE,AIR_QUAL_INDEX,ID_STATION)
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2020-03-29 01:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') , '5' , '2' , '10' , '0' , '7' FROM DUAL
```

and this not:

```
INSERT INTO LUFT_DE_VALUES(DATE_TIME,ID_COMP,ID_SCOPE,LUFT_VALUE,AIR_QUAL_INDEX,ID_STATION)
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2020-03-29 02:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') , '5' , '2' , '10' , '0' , '7' FROM DUAL
```

so it does not work with the time 02:00:00, 01:59:00 or 03:00:00 is working

Thanks in advance,

Andreas

Comment: can you share your create table and wriet the complete error message

Comment: when do you go to daylight saving where your system is based?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL incorrect datetime value error for valid dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635129/mysql-incorrect-datetime-value-error-for-valid-dates)

Answer (score 0):

Both work fine for me on MySQL. Are you sure your DATE_TIME column on the table is defined as a DateTime field?